# Simple landing page using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

I have written a simple landing page in Twitter Bootstrap. It works fine, I just want to know if my code is written in a "good-practice" way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

  <!-- Title and Logo -->
  <title>SigmaCubes - Home</title>
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />

  <!-- Metadata -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="author" content="Julian Lachniet" />
  <meta name="description" content="Various HTML and JavaScript projects." />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-light">
  <nav class="bg-dark navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="32px" /></a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CubeSolver</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/biglogo.png" style="max-height: 384px; margin: 32px" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 h3 text-center">Various HTML and Javascript projects.</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 h5 text-center">SigmaCubes.com is the best website on the internet, and the owner of CubeSolver.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good start. I would like to add a few minor things:

## Character encoding

As a good practice, the character encoding should be the first element of the `head` section - or at least it should come before the `title` element:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SigmaCubes - Home</title>
```

> In order for all browsers to recognize a  declaration, it must be
>
> - Within the `<head>` element,
> - Before any elements that contain text, such as the `<title>` element, AND
> - Within the first 512 bytes of your document, including `DOCTYPE` and whitespace

<sup>From Google Code Archive [doctype-mirror - MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/doctype-mirror/wikis/MetaCharsetAttribute.wiki)</sup>

## Be consistent

In HTML5 void elements can have an optional `/` before the closing `>`. As it seems that you prefer to add this slash, use it everywhere and not only on some elements, like here:

> ```
> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
> <meta name="author" content="Julian Lachniet" />
> <meta name="description" content="Various HTML and JavaScript projects." />
> ```

Here are some more information about this topic: [HTML 5: Is it `<br>`, `<br/>`, or `<br />`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1946426/1456376)

## Valid HTML

Images have a mandatory `alt`-attribute:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" height="32px" alt="Some description" />
```

You should add this attribute to all `img` elements. It will not only help people using screen readers to better understand your website, it might also improve SEO.

For more details, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute.

## Indentation

Try to indent elements, if possible.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="img/logo.png" height="32px" />
</a>
```

… is easier to conceive as:

> ```
> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="32px" /></a>
> ```

## Semantics

Your main navigation looks fine. However, the section starting with `<div class="container-fluid">` looks a bit like [divitis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitis).

Learn about HTML5 semantics and how to structure the content of your website. Here're some related articles on w3.org to get started:

- [3.2.1. Semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#elements-semantics)
- [4.3. Sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sections)
- [4.5. Text-level semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#textlevel-semantics)

## Inline styles

Try to avoid inline styles. This might work for a small page like this, but will get complicated as your project grows.

> ```
> <img class="d-block img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/biglogo.png" style="max-height: 384px; margin: 32px" />
> ```

Instead add a custom CSS file in addition to Bootstrap, where you expand existing styles and add new classes as well.

Comment: In bootstrap, isn't a `<div>` necessary for a fluid container? Is there a way I can avoid using this?

Comment: @JulianLachniet Bootstrap classes are not bound to HTML elements. That means, you can easily do: `<article class="container-fluid"></article>`. This can save a lot of wrapper that will only be there for styling. But what I actually meant, were the elements inside this container: `<div class="col-12 h3 text-center"></div>` could be a heading `<h1 class="col-12 h3 text-center"></h1>` or `<div class="col-12 h5 text-center"></div>` could be a paragraph `<p class="col-12 h5 text-center"></p>`.